# MapInfo : Can not load table

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo

I've generated a shapefile using .NET DotSpatial library, when I try to open the file in MapInfo I face below error, `"Cannot open table. unable to open table road."`

[image: Error]

How do I determine what's the problem of generated dbf file?

When I open the dbf file using Open Office and overwrite the file after dummy change everything works fine.

Just uploaded the shapefile and dbf file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/4751faef-1ef8-49df-bff3-fa1bec5f0258)

### Update

This is the helper class which used to generate shapefile.

```
public class ShapeFileWriter
{  
    public static void Write(
        IEnumerable<IGeometry> geometries, DataTable dt, string path, bool overwrite = true)
    {
        var shapeFile = new FeatureSet
        {
            Projection = ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs");
        };
        var columnNames = new List<string>();
        shapeFile.DataTable.TableName = "road";

        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (column.ColumnName.Length > 11)
            {
                column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Substring(0, 9);
            }
            shapeFile.DataTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
            columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
        }
        int index = 0;
        foreach (IGeometry geometry in geometries)
        {
            IFeature addedFeature = shapeFile.AddFeature(geometry);

            addedFeature.DataRow.BeginEdit();
            foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
            {
                object o = dt.Rows[index][columnName];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ToString()))
                {
                    Type dataType = dt.Columns[columnName].DataType;
                    o = dataType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(dataType) : null;
                }
                addedFeature.DataRow[columnName] = o;
            }
            addedFeature.DataRow.EndEdit();
            ++index;
        }

        shapeFile.SaveAs(path, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to open the file in ArcGIS.  Perhaps you need a projection file?

Comment: @Fezter It's British projection, EPSG 27700 
I should update my code to create the prj file

Comment: Yes, let us know if you still have issues after you do that.  Also, can you show your code here so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: @Fezter It didn't work, I am updating the question to share the code.